# Do tendinopathies have the same pathogenesis regardless of where they occur in the human body?

Tags: tendinopathy

Tendinopathies may appear in many areas of the body, such as the rotator cuff, the Achilles tendon, the patellar ligament, the adductors of the hip, the triceps, the flexors and extensors of the elbow, and the plantar fascia (1). Do tendinopathies have the same pathogenesis regardless of where they occur in the human body?

---

- (1) Kraushaar, Barry S., and Robert P. Nirschl. "Current Concepts Review-Tendinosis of the Elbow (Tennis Elbow). Clinical Features and Findings of Histological, Immunohistochemical, and Electron Microscopy Studies*." J Bone Joint Surg Am 81, no. 2 (1999): 259-278. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3315114728031843854&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.